# adding jquery at the very bottom

Tags: 8, theming

I know how to add or attache a jquery/javascript file on the specific page.

My problem is that I'm trying to add jQuery file (included in theme) at the end of every thing in the body tag so any other file or module would not override it but can't figure out yet.

Is there any way to do that?

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: If jQuery is last, no other script will be able to use it, and it would mkae no sense to include jQuery as a result, since it wouldn't be used.
It is included above any scripts that require it. You should be leaving it as that.

Comment: Hi @jaypan, I think my question should have more details so anybody can understand, so check out https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266318/click-on-geomaps-marker-jquery-doesnt-work , this is why I like to do that because I thing geofield_google_map.js or geojson.js is restricting me to run click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a dependancy on your library definition. e.g. if you want your custom.js after geofield then in the library you define custom.js you need to set a dependancy e.g.:

```
mylibrary:
version: VERSION
js:
  js/custom.js: {weight: 0}
dependencies:
  - geofield_gmap/geofield_gmap
```